# Change focus to the editor in Eclipse while searching

Tags: eclipse

This is the scenario, I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>F</kbd> to search for text in the editor and the focus is in the "Find" portion of the editor. Then I want to switch back to the editor without using the mouse to edit the text that was found.

Is this possible? I see an Activate Editor shortcut, but it doesn't seem to work when already in Find mode.

Answer (score 1):

Typical, I discovered the solution about 5 seconds after posting this question - just press <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>-<kbd>TAB</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

In Aptana you have to hit <kbd>Esc</kbd> instead.